# how can I clear a pyqt QTableWidget?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, qtablewidget

I want to clear my QTableWidget.

First of all I select a user in a qcombobox after that I click a qpushbutton and I populate it from database records; when I select other user and I click the qpushbutton to add data I try to clear with:

```
self.tableFriends.clear()
```

The data disappears but the rows remain.

The code I populate with is:

```
def getFriends(self):
    id_us = self.cbUser.itemData(self.cbUser.currentIndex()).toPyObject()
    rowIndex = 0
    self.tableFriends.clear()
    for row in self.SELECT_FRIENDS(id_us):
        self.tableFriends.insertRow(rowIndex)
        for column in range(0,3):
            newItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[column]).decode('utf-8'))
            self.tableFriends.setItem(rowIndex,column,newItem)
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to remove the rows individually, e.g:

```
while (self.tableFriends.rowCount() > 0)
{
    self.tableFriends.removeRow(0);
}
```

You can also try:

```
tableFriends.setRowCount(0);
```

But that may not work, it's been a while since I've used Qt.

Comment: thanks a lot. I added tableFriends.setRowCount(0) and It was enough.